# How to push a modal screen using ReactNavigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using [ReactNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) with a `StackNavigator` for my screens. From time to time, I need to push a modal screen which the user cannot hit "Back" for. It should also transition from bottom to top (similar to native modal controllers in iOS). I'm not sure how to use the `navigate` method to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with ReactNavigation (although it looks nice, I'll take a look), but ReactNative already has a Modal component that does what you want (bottom top is the slide animation that has by default: [Modal](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html)